# Atomically Split File

Tags: linux

Suppose that I have multiple writers to a single regular file under linux. Multiple unsynchronized processes have opened this file in append mode (`O_APPEND`) and write lines of length **<=** `PIPE_BUF` bytes. These writes are synchronized by the operating system and do not interleave.

A single consumer process aims to periodically consume all lines from this file. I am curious if there is a way to atomically split the file or otherwise consume lines in a way that guarantees that incoming appends are not lost.

For instance, the following approach would be racy:

1. Slurp contents of file to memory
2. Truncate file to length 0

A new line could have been appended between these two steps.

This approach is also infeasible:

1. `rename()` file
2. process renamed file

Writers would still be appending to the original file descriptor.

I'm wondering if there is a way to split this file *in a way that does not require modifying the writers*. For instance, this could be accomplished using something like ***flock*** checks on the writers or using a unix socket instead of a file, but doing so would require writer modification.

The question: Is there any OS-provided synchronization mechanism or sequence available to accomplish this, analogously to how the OS synchronizes appends under `PIPE_BUF` length?